# Keras callbacks with CV grid search

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to implement a CV grid search to tune the hyperparameters for a Keras model. Here is my code (runs without errors, but doesn't handle callbacks properly):

```
def create_model(optimizer,lstm_nodes):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_nodes, dropout=0.25))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=15, verbose=0)

#define the grid search parameters
optimizer = ['Adam','SGD']
lstm_nodes = [12,18,24]
param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizer,
                  lstm_nodes=lstm_nodes)

###### here is where the confusion happens ######
filepath = "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{optimizer}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
csv_logger = CSVLogger('log.csv', append=False, separator=',')
callback=[csv_logger,checkpoint]
#################################################

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,cv=5, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(xMat, yMat,validation_split = 0.1,callbacks=fit_params)
```

I am having problems with the callbacks:

1. Saving the best model for each CV fold for each combination of parameners.
2. Properly logging for each combination of parameters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be no way of properly checking-in the model with CV. However, if everything is logged - you can parse through a file and find the best params. Here is how its done:

Define a class that specifies what to do on Epoch-End:

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as f:
            stats = []
            stats.append(str(batch))
            stats.append('Optimizer,' + self.model.optimizer.__class__.__name__)
            stats.append('Batch_size,' + str(self.params['batch_size']))
            stats.append('accuracy,'+str(logs.get('accuracy')))
            stats.append('val_loss,'+str(logs.get('val_loss')))
            f.write(','.join(stats)+'\n')
```

Then initialize the history object and add it to the callback list:

```
history = LossHistory()
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,cv=5, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(xMat, yMat,validation_split = 0.1,callbacks=[history])
```

Modify what params you need to catch in `LossHistory` class as per your needs as well as formatting of the file (this was just an example). [Here is more documentation on callbacks in keras.](https://keras.io/callbacks/)